# Unable to ping gateway & other Linux boxes on same network

Tags: networking, ip, ping

I'm somewhat new to Linux, but I'm trying to network a few Linux machines. I can't seem to be able ping the gateway or the other Linux machines.

My scenario: I have a few Linux boxes set up on a `10.45.89.x` subnet with the gateway being `10.45.89.1`. On all of these, I'm unable to ping anything except `127.0.0.1`. I'm wondering if I need to modify any of the routing tables or hosts file. Below is a few commands and their output. Perhaps I need to check something else?

#### netstat -r output:

```
10.45.89.0   *   255.255.255.0    U
10.112.0.0    *    255.255.0.0    U
169.254.0.0    *    255.255.0.0    U
default    10.45.89.1    0.0.0.0    UG
```

#### /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain  localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain  localhost
9.37.253.154 rpt.rhn.linux.ul.com
```

#### /etc/resolv.conf

```
domain demolotus.com
namserver 127.0.0.1
```

#### /etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
HOSTNAME=st852.demolotus.com
```

#### ip route show dev eth0

```
10.45.89.0/24  proto  kernel  scope  link  src  10.45.89.138
default via 10.45.89.1
```

#### ifconfig

```
eth0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:01:28:CD
inet addr:10.45.89.138  Bcast:10.45.89.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1

eth0:0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:0C:29:01:28:CD
inet addr:10.45.89.139  Bcast:10.45.89.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
```

#### ip addr show dev eth0

```
2: etho0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
link/ether 00:0c:29:01:28:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.45.89.138/24 brd 10.45.89.255 scope global eth0
inet 10.45.89.139/24 brd 10.45.89.255 scope global secondary eth0:0
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *10.112.0.0    \*    255.255.0.0    U* Do you have another network configured on the same interface?  Or are you running a firewall?  And on top of that  *etho0: <* **NO-CARRIER** *,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP>* you don't seem to have a physical connection reported by `eth0`.

Comment: Thanks, I started playing around with it and got it working. One of the problems was it seemed that I had eth0 disabled, which ifup eth0 corrected. Thanks again.

Comment: The "no carrier" means that there is no connection on that interface (bad cable, not plugged in correctly, broken switch at the other end, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on each host, they should have at least their hostname and a corresponding entry in /etc/hosts with their IP in the relevant network, no? ^^
You only show 127.0.0.1 in there, and the "localhost" hostname... So how can it know it is also part of the 192.whatever network and should therefore be able to ping all the other hosts on there?
In other words: just edit the hosts file and add a line with:

```
10.45.89.xxx  st852.demolotus.com
```

xxx being the last IP digit of  st852.demolotus.com in the 10.45.89.X/24 subnetwork

Comment: and restart (stop ; start) networking, or reboot, to have it re-read its hostname and ip and create its routing information.

Comment: I assume the `hostname` command does indeed reply "st852.demolotus.com", otherwise you need to edit the relevant filse for it to know it is its hostname (it's unix/linux/distribution dependant)

Comment: otherwise, even if ping does go out, the remote machine sees it coming from "127.0.0.1" : when replying, it goes to themselves (as 127.0.0.1 will also be that machine's localhost ip) so you never see the packet go back to the machine who originated the ping.